# How can I fix "/home/ubuntu/.cache/winetricks/directx9/directx_Jun2010_redist.exe: no valid cabinets found"?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, wine, winetricks

I want to install DirectX 9 via winetricks. I opened winetricks and clicked "Select the default wineprefix" then "Ok" then "Install a Windows DLL or component". Then I tried installing d3dx9. After that, it failed. Here is the whole terminal text:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ winetricks32
Executing mkdir -p /home/ubuntu
Using winetricks 20200412 - sha256sum: 7651c93e39fcb080483c38836513bf912273a87ea97d137f6b958ed3d9628c3d with wine-5.0.1 and WINEARCH=win32
winetricks GUI enabled, using zenity 3.32.0
Executing w_do_call d3dx9
Executing mkdir -p /home/ubuntu
Executing load_d3dx9 
Executing mkdir -p /home/ubuntu/.cache/winetricks/directx9
Executing cd /home/ubuntu/.cache/winetricks/directx9
Downloading https://download.microsoft.com/download/8/4/A/84A35BF1-DAFE-4AE8-82AF-AD2AE20B6B14/directx_Jun2010_redist.exe to /home/ubuntu/.cache/winetricks/directx9
Executing cd /home/ubuntu
Executing cabextract -q -d /home/ubuntu/.wine32/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp -L -F *d3dx9*x86* /home/ubuntu/.cache/winetricks/directx9/directx_Jun2010_redist.exe
/home/ubuntu/.cache/winetricks/directx9/directx_Jun2010_redist.exe: no valid cabinets found
------------------------------------------------------
Note: command cabextract -q -d /home/ubuntu/.wine32/dosdevices/c:/windows/temp -L -F *d3dx9*x86* /home/ubuntu/.cache/winetricks/directx9/directx_Jun2010_redist.exe returned status 1. Aborting.
------------------------------------------------------
```

So far I have deleted the winetricks folder in the .cache folder and downloading the software manually from the internet, then running with wine, and none of them worked

Note that `winetricks32` is the alias in bashrc for `WINEPREFIX="$HOME/.wine32" WINEARCH=win32 winetricks`